# Printing All Regex Matches

Tags: regex, perl, sed, awk, grep

I'm using the perl/sed commands below to capture and print regex matches, unfortunately, both only print the first match in a line, rather than all matches. How can I modify either or both commands to print all matches? Grep and Awk alternative commands are welcome.

`perl -nle 'print "$1" if /.*([0|1]\.[0-9]{0,2}).*/'`

`sed -rne "s/.*([0|1]\.[0-9]{0,2})/\1/p"`

Comment: Can you show a sample of your input data?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use `while` with the `/g` modifier to the regex instead of an `if`.  Also need to get rid of your needless use of `.*` around the regex.

```
perl -nle 'print $1 while /([0|1]\.[0-9]{0,2})/g'
```

Finally, `[0|1]` should probably just be reduced to `[01]`, unless you want to match a `|` before the period.

Answer (score 2):

```
perl -nle 'print for /([0|1]\.[0-9]{0,2})/g'
```